# Rails. Choose folder instead of file field tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have an application which imports some data from .xslx files. It works fine with single files and multiple files as well. I use file_field_tag functionality for these purposes. But since I have subfolders there I'd like to permit users to choose specific folder to process all files in it including subfolders. 
As I understand file_field_tag doesn't have any possibility to do it.

How can I deal with it?

Comment: All I got is a temporary solution is using .zip file as a storage for all files and folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  HTML does not support uploading of Folders.  Plugins, like [Awesome Uploader](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?103686-Awesome-Uploader-Drag-and-Drop-Swfupload-File-Field) may provide the functionality you are looking for.  They typically zip your folder then upload the zip file.